# Images within nested lists can overflow outside of the post cell

Tags: bug, design, images, list

This was originally noticed [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/46856/8708) but some quick checks show that this is not an issue exclusive to GD.SE. It occurs in both questions and [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248167/216955).

Here's a Demonstration:

1. List

   - [image: sample image to demonstrate overflow]

     - [image: sample image to demonstrate overflow]

---

Image credit [GiantCowFilms](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/46856/8708)